# Ext.grid.Panel get selected record from tbar button

Tags: extjs4

I created a View extend Ext.grid.Panel and also attach a tbar to it, in the toolbar I got 2 buttons [Add] and [Remove] in this question I am focus on the [Remove] command only.

As usual I want to get hold to current selected record in the grid which I want to delete.

so in the controller:

```
init: function() {
 this.control({
   'extendgridlist button[action=remove]': {
      click: this.removeCurrentRow;
    }
 });
}

removeCurrentRow: function(t){
 // how do i get current selected record
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
removeCurrentRow: function(t){
 var grid = t.up('gridpanel');
 var arraySelected =grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
 //assuming you have a single select, you have the record at index 0;
 var record = arraySelected[0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by 'nscrob' should work just fine, I just wanted to point out an alternate method.  Every Ext component can have an 'id' field.  So, if you gave your grid a config option like the following when it was created:

```
id:'my_grid_id'
```

Then, from anywhere including inside your removeCurrentRow function, you could do the following:

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('my_grid_id');
var rows = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
if(!rows.length)
{   //in case this fires with no selection
    alert("No Rows Selected!");
    return;
}
var row = rows[0];
```

As I said, similar to other answers, but just another way of accessing the grid.

Answer (score 0):

In case grid is to `selType = "cellModel"` use code below:

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('id-of-grid');
var recid = grid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition();

if(recid && recid.row){
  var r = grid.getStore().getAt(recid.row)   
  alert(r.data.anyofgridfieldid)
}
```

more details: http://as400samplecode.blogspot.com/2012/01/extjs-grid-selected-row-cell.html

Answer (score 0):

```
...
xtype: 'button',
text: 'Edit',
handler: function() {
    onEdit(this.up('theGrid')); // alias: 'widget.theGrid' in definition
}

...
function onEdit(theGrid) {

if (theGrid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {    
        var rows = theGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        var row = rows[0];
        console.log('Count Rows Selected : ' + rows.length);
        console.log('The Row : ' + row); // columns: 'id', 'name', 'age'
        console.log('Student Id: ' + row.get('id'));
        console.log('Student Name: ' + row.get('name'));
        console.log('Student Age: ' + row.get('age'));
    }
    else {
        console.log('No Row Selected.');
    }
}
```